# Upgrading old projected to MVC 5

Tags: asp.net

I have an old ASP project that I started a few years ago.  All of its pages are `.aspx`.  I'm upgrading the project to MVC 5.  When I added a new `.cshtml` view, I got a bunch of errors like `HtmlHelper does not contain a definition for 'DisplayFor'` in the `.cshtml` file.  I resolved those errors by updating version numbers in my `Web.config` file, as well as changing the line

```
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage">
```

to

```
<pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
```

Now I'm getting a bunch of `The name 'Html' does not exist in the current context` errors in my `.aspx` pages for all of the lines that use Razor (for instance, `<%= Html.TextBoxFor... %>`)

It's been a few years and MVC versions since I've used ASP.  Is there something I'm doing wrong with MVC 5?  Am I not allowed to use `.aspx` pages along with Razor 3?

Comment: You can use them alongside each other. I suggest you create a new app using the built in VS templates. Check the options for MVC and Web Forms and see how it sets things up. I believe the web.config file in the Views folder will import some important namespaces for you.

Comment: As the other comment indicates, you should start from a new ASP.NET MVC web application project. WebForms (.aspx) is a mess, and MVC is modular (which requires a set of NuGet packages and others). So it would be not trivial to add MVC manually to a WebForms project.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try that.